# Is the JavaScript Set data structure supported by all the browser?

Tags: javascript

I am pretty new in JavaScript and I have the following doubt.

Into a script I am using the **Set** data structure. I don't understand if it is supported only by the latest browser version or also from the old version.

What can you say to me?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set#Browser_compatibility

Comment: read the doc before asking on SO :)

Comment: Sets were introduced by ECMAScript 6.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about feature compatibility and you should have checked google first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set#Browser_compatibility) has the following about basic support:

- Chrome 38 and up
- Firefox (Gecko) 13 and up,
- Internet Explorer 11 and up,
- Opera 25 and up,
- Safari 7.1 and up

Other features may or may not be available, see the linked page for reference.

---

It is part of the [ECMAScript 6 specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-set-objects), so you it will be well-supported in the future, but right now, I would not depend on it. But you might use a tool to convert your ECMA 6-complaint code to ECMAScript 5, as it is backwards compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Not all browsers support it now. It is a rather new feature. If you are new to JavaScript, avoid using it.